# Saving specific data from many files

Tags: python-2.7, file, loops, save, directory

I have a folder where a store files from my fitting model in `.txt` format.

My question here is how to write a loop which will take e.g `p1_cen 7.65782003` from this file and append it to a column in a `.csv` file?
The other thing with my question is that number of those files is equal to 288, because I store 5 minute long data from each day. And a loop what I need is to take from those 288 files a specifit data e.g like above, do You have any ideas how to do this?

For now, I have this code, which writes data in `.txt` files from my lmfit model.

```
  with open('S:\Doc\Python\Results\DecompositionBx ' + "{0}".format(Station) + "{0}{1}".format(Start_time_hours_format, Start_time_minutes_format) + ".txt", 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(result.fit_report(show_correl=False))
```

Btw. my files are named accordingly

```
DecompositionBxHylaty0000
...
DecompositionBxHylaty2355
```

UPDATE!!!

So the code from @bobrobbob works:

```
import csv
from datetime import timedelta

data = []

for i in range(288):
    skip = i*timedelta(minutes=5)
    hours, minutes, _ = str(skip).split(':')
    filename = "S:\Dok\Python\Results\DecompositionBx Hylaty%02d%02d.txt" % (int(hours), int(minutes))
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('    p1_cen'):
            data.append(line.split('+')[0])
            break

with open('S:\Dok\Python\Results\data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

I get something like this, which is nearly perfect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit ugly on the time handling, maybe someone will come with a cleaner solution. but it should work nonetheless

```
import csv
from datetime import timedelta

data = []

for i in range(288):
    skip = i*timedelta(minutes=5)
    hours, minutes, _ = str(skip).split(':')
    filename = "DecompositionBxHylaty%02d%02d" % (int(hours), int(minutes))
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('p1_cen'):
            data.append(line.split('+')[0].strip())
            break

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line.split())
```

Comment: Will it read also numbers after `p1_cen` or only this name, because those numbers are the most important thing.

Comment: the whole line.

Comment: Ok, so the code does check all the files, but when it creates a `.csv` file, there is no stored data. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are all your lines in the form `p1_cen:  7.67189318 +/- 0.00000000 (0.00%) (init = 8)`? the split on '+' is not the sexiest but it should work

Comment: Well you did it perfectly, right now it looks like this (check the newest update), maybe You have some ideas how to solve it :)

Comment: as you can see in the update, there is a great improvement since your last code. But there are those `,` of course I know how to handle with them in Excel e.g., but I'd love to eliminate those empty lines and those commas.

Comment: i'm sorry i did not test it well. i hope it's ok now

Comment: Well everything is fine, but gaps between lines are still here, so I have number, gap, number, gap and so on.

Comment: ah, there were spaces before `p1_cen`. you need to strip the line: `data.append(line.split('+')[0].strip())` i'll edit my answer. (unless it is something totally unrelated, then be more precise please)

Comment: I've update with a printscreen my question. I don't know how to say it more precise. You see those gaps between data lines (line 2,4,6 and so on). So my question is how to delete them?

Comment: my bad, i think that's that windows issue. check if it works. i can't reproduce it

Comment: Well nothing has changed.